# SharePoint 2013: Creating custom list in SharePoint using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I'm having a difficult time creating custom lists using the SP JS API. Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
var lciTasksList = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
lciTasksList.set_title('ProjectTasks');
lciTasksList.set_description('Project Tasks');
lciTasksList.set_templateFeatureId('00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100');

var tasksList = newWeb.get_lists().add(lciTasksList);

context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
          alert('lists created');
     }),
     Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
           alert('lists creation failed');
     })
);
```

The templateFeatureId is a custom list template that is based on the Task list type, with 1 additional custom Choice field. The execution method always ends in failure with

> Cannot complete this action. Please try again.

Has anyone had success creating a list dynamically using a custom list template? My ultimate goal here is to use the JS API to create a new subweb (which works fine) and add several lists with custom columns. Is there another way to accomplish the same task?

Any insights would be much appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

So I've gone with adding fields manually using the following:

```
taskList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field ID="{d2861db8-e36f-4c5e-8168-f7da8b010443}" Name="pdProjectStatus" DisplayName="Project Status" Type="Choice" Required="TRUE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInViewForms="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Active</CHOICE><CHOICE>Archived</CHOICE><CHOICE>Proposed</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>'
                , true
                , SP.AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType
            );
```

Still would be interesting to know if the template approach is available, either by a custom list template or by adding pre-existing custom site columns. Adding the fields in this way seems awfully inefficient, especially considering the Choice field type.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs probably due to a missing `List.TemplateType` property. When creating List, `List.TemplateType` property have to be specified.

> Note: in your example Feature ID with value
>   00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100 is used. That feature corresponds
>   to Custom List, **not** a Task List

### How to create a List based on custom list template via JSOM

The following example demonstrates how to create custom Tasks list:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();

var listInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
listInfo.set_title('Project Tasks');
listInfo.set_description('Project Tasks');
listInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.tasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy); 
listInfo.set_templateFeatureId('F9CE21F8-F437-4F7E-8BC6-946378C850F0');
var list = web.get_lists().add(listInfo);

context.executeQueryAsync(
     function () {
        console.log(String.format('List {0} has been created successfully',list.get_title()));
     },
     function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
     }
);
```

### How to determine List `TemplateFeatureId` and `TemplateType` properties

The list of available List template types could be found on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx)

To determine `FeatureId` property, you could *save your list as a template*, then go to List Template Gallery page (`/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx`) and find Feature Id value.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. So the set_templateType takes a base type, which I assume has to be the same base type as the list template used in set_templateFeatureId template?